# How many equations satisfy $y(x) = 2 +\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t}{f(t)}dt$?

Tags: real-analysis

My excuses if it's a duplicate but I can't find it anywhere online. The question is to examine how many functions satisfy the equation:

$$y(x) = 2 +\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t}{y(t)}dt$$

I was stuck at the integration part because I tried to integrate the indefinite part by parts which yielded this:

$$t\frac{ln(y(t))}{y'(t)}-\int \frac{ln(y(t))}{y'(t)}dt$$

I think that's about all info that I have.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please take moment to give [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9340) a read to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: Okay then, let me edit it and give it some more context since I thought it is just a part of the question I was stuck on

Comment: Also, there is no general way of expressing $\int \frac{x}{f(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$ in terms of elementary functions involving $f(x)$ or its derivatives/antiderivatives. (For example, if $f(x)=\log x$ then the integral $\int\frac{x}{\log x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ is proven to be non-elementary.)

Comment: I rephrased the question, maybe it's more clear now

Comment: You have an integral of the type $\int_0^x \cdots$. My first bet would be to try ***differentiating*** both sides, as opposed to performing the integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So following Eevee Trainer, first differentiate both sides to obtain the condition

$$y'(x) = \frac{x}{y(x)}.$$

Separation of variables and integrating yields

$(y(x))^2 = x^2 + C$ with some real constant $C$.

So $y(x)=\pm\left(x^2+C\right)^{1/2}$ constitute (the only) two candidate solutions.

Now the original integral equation yields $y(0)=2$.

Thus, only the "$+$" candidate is a solution for $C=4$.

So $$y(x)=\left(x^2+4\right)^{1/2}$$ is the only one solution, existing for all real $x$